# returning heap-allocated value from function?

Tags: rust

Rust beginner here. Why does this code work??

```rust
fn make_string() -> String {
    let x = String::from("world");
    x
}

fn main() {
    let s = make_string();
}
```

The way I understand the rules, when the closing bracket of `make_string` is encountered, the value of `x` should be dropped, since `x` is the owner and goes out of scope. You could argue that ownership is transferred, but that seems to happen *after* `x` goes out of scope.

Is this a special case for functions, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the rules?

Comment: IMO, the fact that this perfectly valid question exists is a hint that something is wrong with Rust's syntax. How can something as basic as this be non-obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return a value from a function, you **move** the value, essentially transferring ownership from that function to the parent function, which has a larger scope. Since the scope is now larger, the value won't be dropped.

See:

- [Rust by Example: Ownership and moves](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/scope/move.html)
- [The Rust Programming Language: What is Ownership?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html)

Comment: so, calling a function is equivalent to a nested scope?

Comment: Yes, functions essentially create a scope.